# Porting MongoDB to DynamoDB

Tags: mongodb

I just saw this http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/

I've an application written in Java. We store our data in MongoDB now. Our data typically contains 1-page discussion followed by various 1-2 paragraph comments.

I'm wondering how difficult it is to port the above if I want to switch to DynamoDB.

Comment: do you mean migrating your data? or changing your application? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Describe what your data model is and what your application does. Which kind of search you run and all the technologies involved.